# what dependencies my project should have if I'm using JPA in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, jpa

I use JPA, and Hibernate as its implementation. What `maven2` dependencies I **need** to have in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only two things you need are hibernate's entitymanager and then one of the SLF4J logging bundles. Everything else should be pulled in as dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <!-- version 1.5.8 is the latest version that will work with the slf4j-api 
            that's currently bundled with hibernate-parent -->
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using. You may or may not want to keep the exclusion clauses; they make sense for me, since JTA and JPA are already included in the full Java EE APIs which I'm providing elsewhere. And if you're not using Commons Logging, you might want to pick a different slf4j implementation.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3-Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3-Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- match version to the slf4j-api that's required by Hibernate -->
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
```